# Strategy to prevent a competitor from selling part of a disclosure?

Tags: claims, claim-construction

Say I have:

```
Claim 1. A bed-level meter, comprising:
    a (novel and non-obvious) probe; and 
    a (novel and non-obvious) sensor.
```

The probe and the sensor are physically separate (imagine the probe is an unusual magnet), but only together can the bed-level meter operate.

**Problem:** Competitor A may make and sell my probe, and competitor B may make and sell my sensor because they agreed to do so among themselves as they are more clever than my Claim 1 anticipates.

**Question:** How can I use my three independent claims to prevent the above situation with only **one** patent?

---

Or, is this a non-issue due to the following:

> Indirect Infringement means any form of alleged patent infringement where the accused infringer is not directly infringing the subject patent right(s), **but is in some manner liable for a Third Party’s direct infringement** of the subject patent right(s) by, for example (without limitation), supplying designs, parts or instructions to the Third Party that enable such Third Party to infringe directly the subject patent right(s). Indirect Infringement includes without limitation contributory infringement and inducing infringement. ([REF](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/indirect-infringement))

Answer (score 1):

If the probe is novel and non-obvious and the sensor is novel and non-obvious claim one or both of them stand-alone. I understand you want to minimize the total number of patents, so pick the best one and include an independent claim on just it. If that is granted no one can make it, so obviously no one can make the "bed-level meter" or anything else it would be a part of.

An independent claim could be directed, for example, to the probe. It defines the probe and patents the probe as a stand-alone invention. Then have dependent claims like "The probe of claim 1 in combination with a sensor [define sensor]; the probe and sensor configured [. . . ] so as to constitute a bed-level meter that [. . . ]."

You can describe both items to a level that supports claims for each, and later you could decide to file a divisional for the other as a stand-alone item. Claims can change after filing but are constrained by the specification as filed.

Yes, alleging indirect infringement by inducing infringement is a big help. If they actually conspire to jointly offer the components, point to each other's products, and instruct how to practice your invention you have a stronger case.

I would advise to have a method claim as well as an apparatus claim. Speaking of claims, it is not that expensive ($120 as of 10/22) for a micro-entity (I assume) to have an additional independent claim.

One approach is to draft more claims than you actually plan to file and make sure that all of the claims (included or not) are supported by written description and enablement.